# Sticky sidebar for Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a sticky sidebar just like the one [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) is using.

Currently, I am using Angular 7.0 and Bootstrap 4.x. I just want to do the sticky like sidebar like in the components page of AngularUI (see link above). However, I can't seem to find the feature in the list of components.

So far, I've inspected the page in the `components` section of `ng-bootstrap` demo page, it uses `ngb-sidenav` but I'm not sure though. Anyone knows where or what library should I use?

I've been trying to find a suitable library but most of them are either for AngularJS (1.x) or paid library.

**>>> UPDATE <<<**

I'm thinking of using `position-sticky` class and apply it to my vertical `navs` component. This might do the trick but I'm still gonna test this. I'm going to update this after I test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work. For those who are looking for the solution for having a sticky functionality, you may use bootstrap's `sticky-top` class. Just see its [description](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#sticky-top)

My fix is using bootstrap itself and not `ng-bootstrap`. Just `sticky-top` and a bunch of css styles to suite my needs.

Also, adjust accordingly to your needs.